# "Header File "Only able to be read in one class and other init methods won't work in other files

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been stumped on this for awhile. I have asked multiple developers  I know and they think I have forgotten to "#import the .h file".  But I know  I have, I have tested the class in more than one file in my project.  It only works in the "VNDecalLevelListViewController.h" ( which I will post its implementation if a picture).  When I try and call my "initForNewDecal" method for my "VNDecalCreatorViewController.h" class in my "VNAdminViewController.h" class I received the error that this method has not been declared in "VNDecalCreatorViewController.h".  But when I call it in my "VNDecalLevelListViewController.h" class it works.

I am able to allocate and use "init" to create the object and it loads with a work around I made. But I am new to programming and I can tell there is definitely a better solution.

As you will soon see as i got to allocate the VNDecalCreatorViewController in the " VNAdminViewController" the option to initialize VNDecalCreatorViewController with the proper initializer "initForNewDecal" isn't even a option.

Anyone know why this is happening ? I want to write the code right I am trying to figure out why my header file is only being read in one class.

Comment: How can anyone here help without seeing the relevant code?

Comment: its not letting me post the code

Comment: Edit the question then copy and paste the relevant bits of code. Be sure you take the time to properly format it so it's readable. This means you must indent the code 4 spaces in your question.

Comment: If Cmd+Shift+K doesn't fix it, then post the code.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is because you mutually imported between the two class Creator and Level. I mean you may have `#include "VNDecalCreatorViewController.h"` in VNDecalLevelListViewController.h and vice versa. The solution is to use `@class` to forward declare any classes you may need to reference instead of `#import`'ing the header.

Comment: Thank you I'll try it when I get home

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the method is declared in the header file and implemented in the .m file.